# Sending custom fields in prometheus alerts to pagerduty

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, pagerduty

I have a scenario where I need to send the current time stamp from **Prometheus** to **Pagerduty**. I need to access the current time stamp from the **Custom details** in **Pagerduty** to write **Event Rules** based on the current time.

Currently I can see three fields inside **Custom Details** in **Pagerduty** **["firing", "num_firing", "num_resolved"]**. All the alert related details are inside **"firing"** field but as a single string.

I thought of adding the time stamp to the **Labels** within the **Prometheus event rules**, but the problem is that I will not be able to retrieve that value from the **"firing"** field as it is not in a structured format.

Event details in **Pagerduty** received from **Prometheus**:

```
{
 "client": "AlertManager",
 "client_url": "http://********/",
 "description": "[FIRING:1] **************",
 "event_type": "trigger",
 "incident_key": "********",
 "service_key": "********",
 "details": {
  "firing": "Labels:\n - alertname = ******\n - datacenter = *****\n - instance = ******\n - instance_id = ******\n - instance_type = ******\n - job = ******\n - metrics = ******\n - node = ******\n - pod = ******\n - private_ip = ******\n - public_ip = ******\n - service = ******\n - severity = critical\nAnnotations:\n - description = ******\n - summary = ******\nSource: ******\n",
  "num_firing": "1",
  "num_resolved": "0",
  "resolved": ""
 }
}
```

I need to add the current time stamp in the same level as the **"firing"** field. Is there any way to do this via **Prometheus alert manager** configuration or via the **Alert rules**?

Answer (score 2):

The standard prometheus way for adding additional metadata to alerts is through annotations.

```
- alert: Alert
  for: 5m
  expr: ...
  annotations:
    timestamp: >
      time: {{ query "time()" }}
```

This should add the timestamp annotation to the alert being fired.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I tried this (timestamp: {{ time() }}) and I am getting an error like " cannot unmarshal !!map into string". I enclosed it with double quotes like (timestamp: "{{ time() }}" ) and still getting an error like "function "time" not defined"

Comment: @SujaiSivasamy updated answer which was missing the `query` function that is needed to evaluate PromQL expressions in annotations.

Comment: still I am getting the same error as "cannot unmarshal !!map into string" while running the promtool check rules command. Is there anything to do with the versions that we use?

Comment: It passes the promtool validation now. But the value that I am getting for the query is "timestamp = time: [0xc46b3c7ec0]". Any idea regarding what went wrong?

Comment: Hey, I found that it's an hexadecimal value. When I converted it into decimal and to the human readable time via epoch converter, it gave me the time as "GMT: Sunday, September 15, 1996 5:51:24.928 PM", which is wrong. I am not sure what I missed here.

Answer (score 2):

```
- alert: Alert
  for: 5m
  expr: ...
  annotations:
    timestamp: >
      time: {{ with query "time()" }}{{ . | first | value | humanizeTimestamp }} {{ end }}
```

I have solved same problem, as above. 
Cheers.!

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add this as a custom detail to the alertmanager.yaml .

```
details:
  time: {{ query "time()" }}
```

Note that this adds the time from alertmanager's point of view so might contain a small delay.